# Are there any add-ons, tools or plug-ins for Internet Explorer which act like Firebug?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, internet-explorer, firebug

Firebug is very handy for Firefox . I could test different style at run time with web pages. However sometimes it's necessary to do the same in Internet Explorer.

Are there any tools, add-ons or plug-ins for IE that I could test different styles on web pages with at run time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, there's an online version called [FireBugger](http://www.firebugger.com/). Alternatively, you can also use FireBug Lite in IE by following these [instructions](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-firebug-for-browsers-other-than-firefox/).

Answer (score 1):

Firebugger is a Firebug Lite rip-off and they don't even mention they're just using Firebug Lite via proxy.

If you wish the official and most recent version of Firebug Lite use:

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Disclaimer: I work at the Firebug Working Group